# Android - How to implement Google Newsstand like layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm trying to clone the “view article" fragment layout of Google Newsstand app. It has an `ImageView` on the top that shrinks to become a `Toolbar` when we scroll downwards, just below the `ImageView` lies a `TextView` that contains the text content of the article. While creating the layout itself is pretty easy, implementing the special kind of scroll effect that shrinks the `ImageView` into a `Toolbar` is pretty tricky. Since, most of the updated Google Apps containing material design(e.g. - Play Store, Google+, etc.) contains similar kind of layouts, I was wondering if there's any widget/custom library available for the same. If so, what is it called and how to implement it?

Here's what the layout looks like:

[image: layout]

Comment: The pattern is also used in Google's I/O Scheduler 2014, which is open source: https://github.com/google/iosched. I saw a video where they said they originally used a transparent to solid toolbar but decided to change it to always be solid. The old style should be in older versions of the app in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries like NotBoringActionBar or Header2ActionBar, but, as the babe says, they're Action Bars and in Lollipop they are deprecated.

Anyways, you can find them on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the 'Flexible Space with Image' pattern. It is a popular scrolling technique. The new Android Design Support Library enables you to implement this with ease. [This post](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/) should help you make it.